# How to load html source template from external url

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, webpack

I have to use a full source html template containing logos, headers and footers etc as the base for my webpage.

```
<html>
<head>
Template content
</head>
<body>
  <div>Template content</div>
  <div>Template Content</div>
  <div #id="customapp">Webpage Content</div>
  <div>Template Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am to replace a element within the page such as `<div #id="customapp"></div>` with my custom application.

Is there a way to create a html/javascript page dynamically loads and renders the template html and includes my application given the hosted url of the template html?

For example of what I am trying to acheive:

Transform the following html application using the above template with the template url,

```
<div>My Custom App Content</div>
```

into

```
<html>
<head>
Template content
</head>
<body>
  <div>Template content</div>
  <div>Template Content</div>
  <div>My Custom App Content</div>
  <div>Template Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My goal is have any further changes of the source html automatically reflect on the webpage without any action from me.

The application is currently using vue and webpack.

Comment: Are you thinking of using iframe?

Comment: @FarhadYasir Not sure how iframe can help. I want to load and render the webpage's template dynamically, not the content

Comment: Can you add a sample with the source template please?

Comment: @FarhadYasir it is basically a full working html page, with just a `div` component that is to be replaced

Answer (score 1):

You can load the external template by calling it inside an iframe. The following `loadExternalWebpage` function is creating an iframe, loading the template in the iframe and append it to the `customapp` div.

But to use an iframe you should aware of the **security risk** as you are loading an external url.

```
<html>
  <head>
   Template content
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Template content</div>
    <div>Template Content</div>
    <div #id="customapp">Webpage Content</div>
    <div>Template Content</div>
 </body>
 <script>
    function loadExternalWebpage() {
      const selector = document.getElementById('customapp');
      const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.src = 'your_external_url';
      selector.appendChild(iframe);
   }
   loadExternalWebpage(); 
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if what I'm clear, but what I'm trying is the inverse. I have control on my web application, not on the template html source.

Comment: @user113531 Are you trying to inject your web application in an html template in build time?

Comment: Not at build time, but in the client browser. I want to build a application that injects itself in an html template. I dont want to keep rebuilding my application each time the template changes.

Comment: TBH, not sure what you are trying to achieve. My suggestion create a server side render web application and share the url with above loadExternalWebpage to the template html. So if you need to rebuild your template html it won't impact the web application. That means there are two separate application which will build separately.